# "Es gibt interessante Gebäude in der Region." or "Es sind interessante Gebäude in der Region."?

Tags: word-choice, verb

Which is correct and why? "Es gibt interessante Gebäude in der Region." or "Es sind interessante Gebäude in der Region."? Thanks.

Comment: Both are correct although the first one is more idiomatic in most cases.

Comment: In some regions one says "Es hat interessante Gebäude in der Region." But this is not High German and you should avoid using it.

Comment: @infinitezero that is an answer

Answer (score 1):

As @infinitezero correctly comments, both variants are acceptable.

*Sind* is less favoured, since *sein* is a rather colorless auxiliary verb.
This auxiliary function can be seen from the slightly modified example:

> Es sind interessante Gebäude in der Gegend verstreut.

Opposed to this [geben](https://www.dwds.de/wb/geben) (see meaning 14) at least indicates, that existence is talked about.

Both sentences may be improved with more context or more focus like:

> - Es gibt viele interessante Gebäude in der Region, die besichtigt werden können.
> - Man findet viele interessante Gebäude in der Gegend.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning there are different grammatical structures in the two versions. If I understand correctly, in the first one, *es* is the grammatical subject and *geben* is 3rd person singular. In the second, *Gebäude* is the subject with *es* merely a placeholder, so *geben* is 3rd person plural. The second version is more English-like with *es sind* pretty much a literal translation of *there are*. The phrase *es gibt* seems to have no corresponding version in English.